# Problems with a Union Query with an image/varbinary field

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, union, varbinary

I'm having some problems with the following Query:

```
SELECT  v.idnum
       ,v.full_name
       ,convert(varbinary(max),s.signature)  as Sig
FROM         AppDB.dbo.v_People1 AS v INNER JOIN
                      OtherDB.dbo.Signatures AS s ON v.idnum = s.idnum

UNION

SELECT  v.idnum
   , v.full_name
   , convert(varbinary(max), s.signature) as Sig
FROM         AppDB.dbo.v_People2 AS v INNER JOIN
                      AppDB.dbo.Signatures AS s ON v.idnum = s.idnum
```

When i run them each of the queries separately without the union they execute quickly (<5 seconds), but when i run it using the union it's taking forever to execute (infact all it says is executing. I haven't seen it run successfully)

In OtherDB.dbo.Signatures the signature field is a varbinary(max) and in AppDB.dbo.Signatures the field is an image which is why i am using the convert expression.
Does anyone know what the problem might be and how i can go about fixing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it's because you are using a UNION instead of a UNION ALL.  UNION by itself will remove duplicate rows between the data sets.  This may be causing a delay on your blob field.  See if there is a difference using UNION ALL.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!
 Why would checking to see if a row was duplicate make it so much slower though? There were only 40 rows within the first query and around 10 rows within the second

Comment: It has to do with your blob field, they are not really comparable (can't use a DISTINCT on them either), so it made sense the UNION would choke on it.  I can look around for a more technical explanation.